# What is tensorflow.python.ops

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have searched it in tensorflow website, but I can not find any information about it. Is it not a tensorflow API? Where can I find it's function?

Comment: It is a module. See the source https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/ops

Comment: Oh, I see the source, but not find the gen_audio_ops，and what’s the difference between the module and API.

Comment: Ops is short from Operations, you can find more here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation. It is not an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API is usually something reserved for end-users. Like keras API, we frequently use keras to create models. The API stands for 'Application Programming Interface'.
The Ops however, is not intended for end-users. It is used by tensorflow API-s to function.
For example. If you use a `tf.data.Dataset` and you make a `map` operation on that dataset, the function that you pass into the `map` is converted to a highly optimized version of what you wrote in python. For that, `tf.python.ops` might be used.
From [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation)

> An Operation is a node in a tf.Graph that takes zero or more Tensor objects as input, and produces zero or more Tensor objects as output. Objects of type Operation are created by calling a Python op constructor (such as tf.matmul) within a tf.function or under a tf.Graph.as_default context manager.
> For example, within a tf.function, c = tf.matmul(a, b) creates an Operation of type "MatMul" that takes tensors a and b as input, and produces c as output.

TL;DR: For starters, you don't need to know all the details about `tf.python.ops`. It's used in backend.

Did this answer help?

Comment: Yeah, I have learnt Keras API, and now I want to learn speech recognition. I found a project called DeepSpeech in github, which is created by Mozilla. But it is difficult for me to understand.